# When rest controller return null body, ajax go to the error method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

env: spring boot 2.0,jackson serialization

my rest controller method will not return any body,just like `ResponseEntity.ok().build()`,but   the ajax don't go to success method,it will go to error emthod,and the error shows "Unexpected end of JSON input"

i tried this:
1.  add the properties into application.properties : `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL`, it still go to error method;
2. update return result like this `ResponseEntity.ok("{}")`,it will ok;

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/import")
   public ResponseEntity<Void> importRecipients(@ModelAttribute UserRecipientDto userRecipientDto,
                                                @CurrentUser @ApiIgnore User user,
                                                @RequestParam ImportType importType,
                                                @RequestParam String name,
                                                @RequestParam List<Long> ids) {
       Collection<MailRecipient> count = this.service.getRecipients(userRecipientDto, importType, ids);
       UserMailRecipientGroup userMailRecipientGroup = new UserMailRecipientGroup(name, USER_RECIPIENT, count, user);
       userMailRecipientGroupService.saveMailRecipientGroup(userMailRecipientGroup);
       return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
   }
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jackson:
      serialization:
        write-dates-as-timestamps: true
        write_dates_with_zone_id: true
      time-zone: GMT
      default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL
```

ajax code block:

```js
    url: url,
    type: type,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    headers: {},
    data: param,
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function success(data) {
      cb(data);
    }, 
error: function error(request, status_code, text_error) {}
```

i expect this:
when my rest method return `ok().build()`, the ajax will go to success method.
i guess ajax convert result to json occur some error, may be some spring boot properties will do it, but i haven't found yet.
thanks!!

Comment: Your body is a class called Long, are you sure that needed? what body json do you think to response?

Comment: You are not returning valid json

Comment: i will update Long to Void,and have a try. In fact, i will return  http status to clien only, but no body

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what class your controller is extending and the import of your ok() method.

Maybe try with [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ok-T-)

```
ResponseEntity.ok().build()
```

Answer (score 0):

From **return ok().build()** you are just returning the Http Status 200 OK Status. Isn't it?

What exactly you have to return to client?

If it is some response you have go for 
***return ResponseEntity.ok().build()*** or

***return Response.ok().entity(someEntity).build();***

and im seeing the return type is ResponseEntity from the code.

Please eloborate the problem.

Edit:

Code would be look like

@PostMapping(value = "/import")

```
public ResponseEntity<String> importRecipients(@ModelAttribute UserRecipientDto userRecipientDto,

        @CurrentUser @ApiIgnore User user, @RequestParam ImportType 

        importType, @RequestParam String name,

        @RequestParam List ids) {


    Collection count = this.service.getRecipients(userRecipientDto, importType, ids);


    UserMailRecipientGroup userMailRecipientGroup = new UserMailRecipientGroup(name, USER_RECIPIENT, count, user);


    userMailRecipientGroupService.saveMailRecipientGroup(userMailRecipientGroup);


    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);


}
```

Comment: in fact, client need 200 http status only, in browser debug ,i have found the 200 status,but  it go into the ajax function error, `error: function error(request, status_code, text_error) {}`. in my rest controller ,i didn't return any body, but http status 200  only. how can i modify it ,let it go into the ajax success method.

Comment: @steven thats because your mapping return type is ResponseEntity<Void>, what you can do is change the return type into ResponseEntity<String> and 
return new  ResponseEntity<String>( HttpStatus.OK)

Answer (score 0):

how a silly question is it,   I should not doubt my controller. In fact, the problem happens on front-end, my workmate support an error json resolver!!